# Python sparse matrix C with elements c_ij = sum_j min(a_ij, b_ji) from sparse matrices A and B

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two sparse matrices **A** and **B** where **A** and **B** have the same number of columns (but potentially different numbers of rows). I'm trying to get a sparse matrix **C** with elements c_ij = sum_j  min(a_ij,b_ji), where a_ij and b_ij are elements of **A** and **B**, respectively.

Can this be done efficiently, and ideally sparsely? Even densely would be okay, but the matrices involved will be huge (tens of thousands of rows) and very sparse.

**Details:**
The analogy is with standard (mathematical) matrix multiplication, but instead of summing the product of elements, I want to sum the minimum of elements.

An example will help. Using standard matrix multiplication **A** * **B** gives elements c_ij = sum_j a_ij * b_ji for elements a_ij in **A** and b_ij in **B** with i and j as row and column indices, respectively.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

A = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], 
                [0, 0, 3], 
                [4, 0, 5]])

B = csr_matrix([[2, 0, 0], 
                [0, 0, 3], 
                [6, 0, 0]])

C = A * B
print(f"\nC = A * B = \n{C}")
```

gives

```
>>> 
C = A * B = 
  (0, 2)    6
  (0, 0)    2
  (1, 0)    18
  (2, 0)    38
```

where

c_31 = 38 = sum_j ( a_3j * b_j1 ) = 4 * 2 + 0 * 0 + 5 * 6 = 38.

For each element of C, I want the sum of minimums min(a_ij * b_ji) instead of the sum of products a_ij * b_ji:

c_31 = sum_j min(a_3j,b_j1) = min(4,2) + min(0,0) + min(5,6) = 7.

Comment: For dense  arrays, matrix product can be done with a broadcasted multiply followed by sum.  While not as fast as the BLAS kind of `matmul` it's still good, and the idea can be adapted to taking a minimum between the arrays first.  Sparse doesn't do broadcasting, so that's not an option.  The `csr` matmul uses a partly compiled method developed years ago, one compiled run to determine the number of nonzero terms, and a second to actually fill them.  I haven't looked at the details  I doubt if it can done efficiently in pure python code.

Comment: The sparse matmul works directly with the `csr` format arrays, `data`, `indices`, `indptr`.  Your `B` is `csr`, `BT` is then `csc`, but I believe the multiply it will be converted to a `csr`.    There have been SO that explore using those array directly for various operations.  It's not trivial, but it helps if you understand the `csr` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal dense arrays this would be done more easily with a three-dimensional array, but those are unavailable in sparse form. Instead,

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_array, coo_array

# If you're able to start in COO format instead of CSR format, it will make the code below simpler
A = csr_array([
    [1, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 3],
    [4, 0, 5],
    [4, 0, 5],
    [1, 1, 6],
])
B = csr_array([
    [2, 0, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 3, 2],
    [6, 0, 0, 4],
])
m, n = A.shape
n, p = B.shape

# first min argument based on A
a_coo = A.tocoo(copy=False)
a_row_idx = ((a_coo.col + a_coo.row*(n*p))[None, :] + np.arange(0, n*p, n)[:, None]).ravel()
a_min = coo_array((
    np.broadcast_to(A.data, (p, A.size)).ravel(),  # data: row-major repeat
    (
        a_row_idx,                 # row indices
        np.zeros_like(a_row_idx),  # column indices
    ),
), shape=(m*n*p, 2))

# test; deleteme
a_min_dense = np.zeros((m*n*p, 2), dtype=int)
a_min_dense[:, 0] = np.repeat(A.toarray(), p, axis=0).ravel()
assert np.allclose(a_min_dense, a_min.toarray())

# second min argument based on B
b_coo = B.tocoo(copy=False)
b_row_idx = ((b_coo.row + b_coo.col*n)[None, :] + np.arange(0, m*n*p, n*p)[:, None]).ravel()
b_min = coo_array((
    np.broadcast_to(B.data, (m, B.size)).ravel(),  # data: row-major repeat
    (
        b_row_idx,                # row indices
        np.ones_like(b_row_idx),  # column indices
    ),
), shape=(m*n*p, 2))

# test; deleteme
b_min_dense = np.zeros((m*n*p, 2), dtype=int)
b_min_dense[:, 1] = np.tile(B.T.toarray().ravel(), (1, m)).ravel()
assert np.allclose(b_min_dense, b_min.toarray())

# Alternative to this: use two one-dimensional columns and hstack
ab = (a_min + b_min).min(axis=1)
addend = ab.reshape((-1, n))

# scipy sparse summation input is sparse, but output is NOT SPARSE. It's an np.matrix.
# If that matters, you need to run a more complex operation on 'ab' that manipulates indices.
# deleteme
total = addend.sum(axis=1).reshape((m, p))

# Example true sparse sum
separators = np.insert(
    np.nonzero(np.diff(addend.row))[0] + 1,
    0, 0,
)
sparse_total = coo_array((
    np.add.reduceat(addend.data, separators),
    (
        addend.row[separators],
        np.zeros_like(separators),
    )
), shape=(m*p, 1)).reshape((m, p))

# test; deleteme
ab_dense = (a_min_dense + b_min_dense).min(axis=1)
sum_dense = ab_dense.reshape((-1, n)).sum(axis=1).reshape((m, p))
assert np.allclose(ab.toarray().ravel(), ab_dense)
assert np.allclose(sum_dense, total)
assert np.allclose(sum_dense, sparse_total.toarray())

print(sum_dense)
```

Other notes: don't use `_matrix`; it's deprecated in favour of `_array`.

The above operates on different example matrices from yours, deliberately, because it's impossible to reliably develop array manipulation code when all of the dimensions are of the same size. However, when I modify them to be the same as your original arrays, I get

```
[[1 0 2]
 [3 0 0]
 [7 0 0]]
```

Comment: This is not what the OP want to compute: the output should be a matrix and `c_33` must be 4 based on the question. This answer compute a vector for the provided example without the value 4. I think you though `A * BT` is an element-wise product but it is not as described in the OP question : it is a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes, it is not just a classical matrix multiplication, but a kind of custom matrix multiplication where `a*b` replaced by `min(a,b)` (so it is not really a matrix multiplication in the end). This is confirmed by `c_33 = sum_j min(a_ij,b_ji) = min(4,6) + min(0,0) + min(0,5) = 4` (which is correct : there is no error of transposition). Your code do not gives `c_33 = 4`.

Comment: Thank you Reinderien for this post, it's very helpful. Jérôme is however correct in noting that the matrix C should be 3x3 with elements c_ij equalling a sum of minima, for example, c_33 = min(a_31,b_13) + min(a_32,b_23) + min(a_33,b_33). I will update my question to make this more clear, I think the transpose part is causing confusion and not strictly necessary, now that I look at it again.

Comment: The example was malformed, my apologies, but the solution proposed here is still not quite what I'm after, C should be a 3x3 is a sum of the minima of the relevant (a,b) pairs from the matrices A and B. The transpose bit that was in the question before was unnecessary, my apologies.

Comment: @RMM That should be closer to reality

Comment: So helpful, thank you. I'm trying to implement this now in my setting.